# ServiceNOW not able to update work_notes

Tags: rest, postman, servicenow-rest-api

I'm trying to update an incident's work_notes from POSTMAN with the below details, but it's not updating them. However I have referred the ServiceNOW documentation and trying the REST call the same way but still data is not getting updated.

Other fields like comments, description are getting updated or added, but only work_notes is not getting added.

Let me know if there are any other configurations are missing.

```
URL - https://dev55678.servicenow.com/api/now/table/incident/b5f4e0c387d32950545bdc283cbb356d

Method - PUT

Request - 

{
    "work_notes":"..Work notes to be added.","comments":"Comments to be added"
}
```

I'm getting a 200 OK response but the work_notes are not getting updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that other fields such as comments and description are being updated but work notes aren't suggest that the user sending the update doesn't have the ITIL role capable of doing so.

Normal users are able to update all the other fields you've described however you need ITIL permissions to add a work note.

Hope this helps!